# Калькулятор на базовом питоне

Tags: python

Я новичок в Python. Я пытался сделать простой калькулятор, но не могу найти проблему. Любая помощь с этим будет принята с благодарностью. Спасибо.

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def div(num1, num2):
    return num1/num2

def multi(num1,num2):
    return num1*num2

def main():
    operation = input("What do you want to do?(+, -, *, or /):")
    if (operation != "+" and operation != "-" and operation != "*" and operation != "/"):
        print("Your input is invalid. Please enter a valid input.")
    else:
        num1 = float(input("Enter value for num1: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter value for num2: "))
        if (operation == "+"):
            print(add(num1, num2))
        elif (operation == "-"):
            print(subtract(num1, num2))
        elif (operation == "*"):
            print(multi(num1,num2))
        elif (operation == "/"):
            print(div(num1,num2))

    main()
```

Comment: Вы бы хотя бы намекнули, что за проблему вы не можете найти?...

Comment: скорее всего main() надо посунуть в левую сторону

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def add(num1, num2):
return num1 + num2

def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2

def div(num1, num2):
    return num1/num2

def multi(num1,num2):
    return num1*num2

def main():
    operation = input("What do you want to do?(+, -, *, or /):")
    if (operation != "+" and operation != "-" and operation != "*" and operation != "/"):
        print("Your input is invalid. Please enter a valid input.")
    else:
        num1 = float(input("Enter value for num1: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter value for num2: "))
        if (operation == "+"):
            print(add(num1, num2))
        elif (operation == "-"):
            print(subtract(num1, num2))
        elif (operation == "*"):
            print(multi(num1,num2))
        elif (operation == "/"):
            print(div(num1,num2))

#Тут у Вас был лишний отступ
main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Лишний отступ перед `main()`, уберите его и всё станет нормально.